# Handle error from URI in Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I use Bootstrap table to present collection. Table is filled from url: MyAjaxAddress , which is declared in HTML code. But somethime when something goes wrong on server side, I want to display info messsage.

```
<table data-url="MyAjaxAddress" ... >
    <thead>
```

My question is: how to fire javascript function when MyAjaxAddress from table attribute return HTTP 500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution

```
$('#bootstrapTableId').bootstrapTable({

    onLoadError: function (status) {

        MyJsFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm right.

*data-url* wants a *Json-Array*.

So you can first get your Json via Ajax, check the http-state and then assign it to the table.

```html
var json = {};

$.ajax({url: "MyAjaxAddress",
  success: function(data){
    json = data;
  },
  error: function(xhr){
    alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});

$('table').data("url", json);
```